# Show $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ac}{bc}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ac}{bc}$$
>   if $b$, $c \neq 0$.

I do not understand at all, could you explain?

Comment: You need to provide more information

Comment: Hint: $(bc)^{-1}=c^{-1}b^{-1}$ because $(bc)c^{-1}b^{-1}=b(cc^{-1})b^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score 3):

For $x,y,z,w$ integers, with $y,w$ nonzero. You have the following equivalence:
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{z}{w}$$
if and only if
$$yw=yz.$$
So that if $b$ and $c$ are both nonzero, you have that 
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ac}{bc}$$
since
$$a\cdot bc = b\cdot ac.$$

Comment: Another way is defining $\frac{x}{y}$ to be $xy^{-1}$ if $y\neq 0$.

Comment: I believe you mean $xw = yz$, because of *cross multiplication*.

Comment: hm, idk what you mean with cross multiplication in this context. That's the definition of the multiplication in this case

Comment: We have $$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{z}{w}$$ Now we cross-multiply, meaning to multiply both sides by the opposing denominator. Therefore, we have $$\begin{align} \frac{xw}{y} &= z \tag*{when we multiply both sides by $w$} \\ \Rightarrow xw &= yz \tag*{when we multiply both sides by $y$} \end{align}$$ Not $yw = yz$. Otherwise, $w = z$ and thus $\dfrac xy = \dfrac zw = 1$

Comment: Do you see what I mean now? This must also imply that $x = y$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ac}{bc}$$
$$\because \frac{a\require{cancel} \cancel{c}}{b\cancel{c}}$$.
$$\because \ = \ \text{because/since}$$

The second equation is saying that the $c$'s cancel out. Why? Well when we split the fraction:
$$
\frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b}\times\frac{c}{c} \\
\implies \frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b}\times1 \\
\therefore \frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b}
$$.
$$
\begin{align} \implies \ &= \ \text{which implies that / follows that / yields} \\
\therefore \ &= \ \text{thus/hence/therefore} \end{align}
$$

I hope you know now :)

P.S. Have you learnt what values are when raised to a *negative* value?

Answer (score 2):

1. What is $5/5$? Hopefully you answered $1$. What is $2/2$? Also $1$. What is any number $n$, divided by itself, $n$? Also $1$. We write this as $n/n = 1$ (or $\frac{n}{n} = 1$; same thing).
2. What is $5\cdot 1$? Hopefully you answered $5$. What is $2\cdot 1$? $2$. What is any number $n$, times $1$? It is $n$.
3. Consider a number like $2$. Say we multiply it by $1$. It is still $10/5$, due to what we said in #2. What if instead of saying $1$, we included an expression equal to $1$, like $2/2$? $2 \cdot 2/2 = 2$ because of both #1 and #2 - the second part, $2/2$, comes out to $1$, as per #1, and the multiplication comes out to $2$ as per #2. We can generalize this to saying that some number $a \cdot \frac{n}{n} = a$.
4. Let's reform $a$. We can make $a$ any number - what if we had $a/b$? Then $a/b \cdot n/n = a/b$. Multiplying fractions, we get $an/bn = a/b$.
5. Replace $n$ with $c$ and we get $$\frac{ac}{bc} = \frac{a}{b}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac ab = \frac ab*1 = \frac ab*\frac cc = \frac {ac}{bc}$.

==== details =====

Oh boy....

By definition $\frac ab$ is the number $x$ so that $x*b = a$.

If we multiply both sides by $c$ we get $x*(bc) = (ac)$.

The definition of $\frac {ac}{bc}$ is the number $y$ so that $y*(bc) = (ac)$.

Well, as we can see by above equation.  $x$ and $y$ both must be the same number.

So $\frac {ac}{bc} =y = x = \frac {a}{b}$.

..... another way.......

Do you accept that i) $\frac ef*\frac gh = \frac {eg}{fh}$ and do you accept ii) that $\frac kk = 1$ for all $k$?

If so $\frac {ac}{bc} = \frac ab * \frac cc = \frac ab * 1 = \frac ab$.

To prove i) $\frac ef = x$ means that $fx =e$.   $\frac gh = y$ means $g = hy$.

So $(eg) = (fg)xy$ so that means $\frac {eg}{fg} = x*y = \frac ef*\frac gh$.

To prove ii)  $\frac kk$ is the number $x$ so that $k*x = k$.  $1$ is that number.